# Unlock screen with device manager

Tags: lock-screens, file-transfer, broken-screen, android-device-manager

so im trying to unlock my galaxy s4 screen, using google device manager, or something similar (any suggestion ?). cuz my screen recently cracked a i wanna get backup from all my data and reset it before i change the screen entirely. but an app like "Kies" requires the screen to be unlocked in order to enable any file transfer! can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154). Instead of trying to get your supposed solution working, let's better work on the issue at hand. I've just added the `broken-screen` tag to your question, please start checking out [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) for first aid. Especially take a look at the "data recovery" section there.

Answer (score 0):

Unlocking the screen from outside is not possible. (without root privileges).

If you have a custom recovery installed then you can boot into it and make a backup via `adb shell`